# Start a route on suspend state and scheduling the resume

Tags: java, timer, routes, apache-camel

I need the following behaviour for some Camel routes: a route must start in active state, but must also be suspended if the current time is between X AM and Y PM.

All the routes start with a timer in the from (e.g every 30 seconds, every 5 minutes, ...) but I want that the route is fired only in the given period of the day.

I am able to schedule, using a ScheduledRoutePolicy, the automatic suspend and resume of a route that is currently active and running.

But I don't understand how to start the route in suspended state if, for example, current time is the period in which the route should be suspended.
The RoutePolicy schedules a job that suspend/restart the route, but when Camel start my routes are all fired, no matter if the route was supposed to be suspended.

The only way in which I can achieve it, seems putting in the timer the time parameter, thus setting the time of the day of the first event.

In this case, if it is before the scheduled time, then the timer does not fire any event. The ScheduledPolicy will then take care of suspending the route, and then it will resume the route after some time.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the route to not start with the autoStartup option. See this page for more details: http://camel.apache.org/configuring-route-startup-ordering-and-autostartup.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I knew about the autostartup=false parameter. But doing that, the route initial status would be stopped. From the Camel docs, their advice is to suspend/resume routes, not to start/stop them http://camel.apache.org/maven/current/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/CamelContext.html

Comment: Doesn't matter. The route policy will handle that as well to start the route the 1st time, and then suspend/resume. Though you can configure this in your route policy what you want to do.

Comment: I read the source code of the CronScheduledRoutePolicy, a class that extends the ScheduledRoutePolicy, but it doesn't resume a route "stopped", it resumes only the routes suspended. So, it is a little tricky, and I think I will have to write a customized policy for managing my case.